# Madcreator Rabinfingerprint command line vs java/scala program

Tags: java, scala, fingerprint, rabin

I'm using Madcreator's Rabinfingerprint java library in a scala program, https://github.com/themadcreator/rabinfingerprint.

Using the command line I generate an irreducible 53 degree polynomial:

```
java -jar rabinfingerprint.jar -polygen 53
31DF3F8C7356D3
```

Then fingerprint the file:

```
java -jar rabinfingerprint.jar -p 31DF3F8C7356D3 file.txt
1847CCD86D5DE5 file.txt
```

The problem I'm having is producing the same output, given the same input, using code.

```
// Can't create Polynomial from hex above, so convert hex to long and use that:
val polynomial = Polynomial.createFromLong(14037737891124947L)
// val p = java.lang.Long.toString(14037737891124947L, 16) 
// p = 31DF3F8C7356D3 same as command line input

val rabin = new RabinFingerprintLong(polynomial)
rabin.pushBytes(text.getBytes)

val fp = rabin.getFingerprintLong
println(java.lang.Long.toString(fp, 16))  // 1acc76a73eed1f
fp.toString // 7543159378603295

// Where is 1847CCD86D5DE5 ?
```

Comment: When you run fingerprint on file from command line it produces every time the same result?

Comment: With the same polynomial, yes.

Comment: How did you get `text`? You need to be sure you haven't removed line breaks, etc. from the string.

Comment: Grr, tunnel vision.  Thanks Travis.  Changing to use val text = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filepath).map(_.toByte).toArray, previously getLines().mkString(...), has fixed it.  Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @10cls: Done—glad my guess helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I note in a comment above, if you're reading the contents of the file into a string, you need to be careful that you don't strip out line breaks or any other characters—if for example you're calling `source.getLines.mkString` you're going to lose the line breaks, which means you won't see the same results as the driver class, [which uses Guava's `ByteStreams.toByteArray`](https://github.com/themadcreator/rabinfingerprint/blob/65ef1c54762e9eff317ae9efef18311fe95de246/src/main/java/org/rabinfingerprint/Main.java#L29).